# Supabase throws Payload too large when I try to upload a file using the uploadBinary method in flutter web

Tags: flutter, supabase

I am trying to upload an image to a supabase bucket in flutter web, but I keep running into this error
`StorageException(message: The object exceeded the maximum allowed size, statusCode: 413, error: Payload too large)`

It does not matter the size of the file I upload.

I am using the uploadBinary method since the upload method doesn't play well with flutter web as stated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/73104386/10630669.

This is the code I'm using to handle the upload.

```dart
Future<void> uploadImages(List<XFile> images) async {
    state = UploadingPictures();
    final client = ref.read(getSupabaseClientProvider);
    final storageClient = ref.read(getSupabaseStorageClientProvider);

    for (var image in images) {
      final extension = image.path.split('.').last;
      final name = image.path.split('/').last;
      final bytes = await image.readAsBytes();

      LoggerUtil.d('bytes: ${bytes.length}',
          tag: '[UploadImagesViewModel].uploadImages');

      storageClient
          .from(SupabaseStorageConstants.serviceFolder)
          .uploadBinary('$name.$extension', bytes)
          .then((value) {
        LoggerUtil.d('uploadImage: $value');
      }).catchError((error) {
        LoggerUtil.e('uploadImage: $error');
        state = ErrorUploadingPictures(error.toString());
      });
    }
    state = SuccessUploadingPictures();
  }
```

My logs

```
Performing hot restart...
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...
Restarted application in 1,349ms.
Got object store box in database supabase_authentication.
***** SupabaseDeepLinkingMixin startAuthObserver
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
│ [UploadImagesViewModel].uploadImages
├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
│ #0   packages/heavens_gate_attendance/shared/utils/logger_util.dart 20:15                            d
│ #1   packages/heavens_gate_attendance/core/pictures/view_models/upload_images_view_model.dart 42:20  uploadImages
├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
│  bytes: 55864
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
│ ###LoggerUtil###
├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
│ #0   packages/heavens_gate_attendance/shared/utils/logger_util.dart 26:15                            e
│ #1   packages/heavens_gate_attendance/core/pictures/view_models/upload_images_view_model.dart 45:45  <fn>
├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
│ ⛔ uploadImage: StorageException(message: The object exceeded the maximum allowed size, statusCode: 413, error: Payload too large)
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

I expect that I can upload the image successfully.

Does anyone know if Supabase has a limit for the request payloads? And if so, how do I increase it?

Comment: Self hosting or what kind ?

Comment: @Q.u.a.n.gL. I am not self-hosting. It is being managed by supabase

Comment: I cant spot any problems. Could you checkthe storage limitation on from dashboard ?https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1154867/155087619-f5f3b811-fb9c-4ea7-a33f-2244dc0d2db8.png

Comment: Thanks. That solved it. I was under the impression that it would just use the global limit that was set.